# URL params for polymorphic url_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I currently have this code:

```
link_to 'add a new baz!', new_foo_bar_baz_path(@foo, @bar, baz: { thing: 'the-value' })
```

which generates this url:

```
http://ganxy.local/foos/1/bars/2/bazes/new?baz%5Bthing%5D=the-value
```

Because of some changes I'm making to my app I want to make the url generation polymorphic. So, something like this:

```
link_to 'add a new baz!', [@foo, @bar, :baz]# : { thing: 'the-value' })
```

Is there a way to add the `?baz%5Bthing%5D=the-value` to the end, or do I need to generate the string manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Rails 3 - Nested resources and polymorphic paths: OK to two levels, but break at three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918345/rails-3-nested-resources-and-polymorphic-paths-ok-to-two-levels-but-break-at)

So you can write

```
link_to 'add a new baz!', polymorphic_url([@foo, @bar, :baz], thing: 'the-value')
```

Comment: Yes, great! There is also `polymorphic_path`, which is what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't recommend to use polymorphic url because it 2x slower than helper method. Check out [my post about this](http://railsguides.net/2013/12/04/rails-url-for-helper-can-be-slow/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
link_to 'add a new baz!', [[@foo, @bar, :baz], thing: 'the-value']
```